# Switch function not working with a variable

Tags: php

I get a value of 2920 from the variable. When I use the variable in the switch function, it does not redirect.

```
<?php
include "dbConn.php";
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as price FROM contactform_entries";
$result =  mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $array = $row; 
    }
}

echo($array['price']); // Value is 2920

$abc=($array['price']);

switch ($abc) {
  case "2920":
    header("Location: http://yahoo.com");  
    break;
  case "2930":
    header("Location: http://google.com");  
    break;
}

?>
```

The value of the variable does not work with switch.

Comment: Don't use `echo` to debug, use `var_dump`. There is nothing special about `2920`. https://3v4l.org/XthkL

Comment: If you echo something first, then redirecting won't work. That has nothing to do with your switch statement. If you just want to test the switch logic then temporarily replace the "header" commands with simple echo statements, to prove which switch branch was used

Comment: P.s. you should be getting a warning message about the header issue. If you don't, enable php error logging and then check the log file after your next test

Comment: `$array = $row;`  would overwrite `$array` on every iteration. If you only have 1 value though you don't need the `loop` and could just assign the `fetch` to `$array` directly. You also don't need parenthesis everywhere.  `echo($array['price'])` and `echo $array['price']` are the same. As would be `$abc=($array['price'])` and `$abc=$array['price']`. I would just use `$row['price']` rather than all the reassigning things you are doing. (e.g. maybe https://3v4l.org/8RoE5)